# Calculate with Javascript / HTML-Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html

I have the price of an order in an PHP variable, let's say $price. This $price is the sum of a daily $rate * $rental_days. In the next step some extras could be added with three dropdowns in HTML. The first and the second are per order, the third per day.

```
<select id="extras_1">
 <option>10 Euros/Order</option>
 <option>20 Euros/Order</option>
</select>
<select id="extras_2">
 <option>20 Euros/Order</option>
 <option>30 Euros/Order</option>
</select>
<select id="extras_3">
 <option>10 Euros/Day</option>
 <option>20 Euros/Day</option>
</select>
```

I would like to add the price of the extras to the basic rate with Javascript, so that the user can see the final price directly. (The final price is calculated with PHP in the last step, so no worries about security.)

I am a total Jacascript newbie. Maybe someone wants to help me? Thank you!

Comment: [ask] but [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am learning javascript, the code below gets the selected options, extracts number part of the option.

```js
function calcuate() {
  
var sum = 0;
var element1 = document.getElementById("extras_1");
sum += Number(element1.value);
var element2 = document.getElementById("extras_2");
sum += Number(element2.value);
var element3 = document.getElementById("extras_3");
sum += Number(element3.value);
console.log(sum);
}
```

```html
<select id="extras_1">
 <option value="10">10 Euros/Order</option>
 <option value="20">20 Euros/Order</option>
</select>
<select id="extras_2">
 <option value="10">20 Euros/Order</option>
 <option value="20">30 Euros/Order</option>
</select>
<select id="extras_3">
 <option value="10">10 Euros/Day</option>
 <option value="20">20 Euros/Day</option>
</select>
<button onclick="calcuate()">calcuate</button>
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? [answer]

Comment: You can cut this code down by almost a 1/3 by just getting the `.value` property of each of the select elements.  There's no need to get the selected index to load the option and get its text.  Also, the option tags have a value property, so using regex isn't strictly necessary, either.